# exercise 19.13 in Algebra (Issac)

Tags: extension-field

Let $F\subset E$ be purely inseparable with $|E:F|=n<\infty$. If $\alpha \in E$, show that ${\alpha}^n \in F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** If $\text{char}(F)=p>0$, then $n=p^k$ for some $k$.